# Rails 5 - How to get User-Agent at server side?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, user-agent

I have the following system architecture:

```
Client (Web app) => Proxy(REST API) => Server (Web App + REST API)
```

First the `Client` sends a `POST request` to the `Proxy`, which sends a `POST` request to the Server.

**Question :** How could I get the client's User-Agent at server side?

I'm kind of lost there.
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Solved.**  Refer to my first answer in the accepted question, right now, I can't edit this question propperly (I'll do it as soon as I'm able to).

Comment: Why do I need the client's User-Agent? I have to send it on an email body (which's already been sent, using SendGrid) after authentication attempt. I'm using HTTPparty to create the requests.

Comment: you should improve your question but adding some code

Comment: Thanks for the insight @NejiSoltani, I'll do add some code, not now because I have to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could read `User-Agent` HTTP header on `Proxy` and then pass it in the following POST from `Proxy` to `Server`.

don't know how in rails-5, but in rails-4 (and I guess API has not changed) in order to read `User-Agent` header you do (in controller):
`request.headers['User-Agent']`

I guess the best option would be to pass it (from `Proxy`) in POST request body to `Server`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @djaszczurowski, I've already solved it before reading this, but your answer was pretty close indeed. I had to read the `User-Agent` in `Client` and add the HTTP Header to the `HTTParty request` (don't know why isn't there by default), after that do the same in `Proxy`, and then only then I could read it at server side.